# I am getting error while installation of openmpi-2.1.1

Tags: 14.04

I am getting this error while installation of openmpi-2.1.1.

ubuntu@localhost:~/Desktop/openmpi/build$ make install all

make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.

pls help me out!

Comment: Please give us a link to the file you downloaded so we may help you.

Comment: Try first: `make all` and then `make install`

Comment: link: https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v2.1/                                                         File: openmpi-2.1.1.tar.gz